# Setting default target group with Yammer embed and open-graph

Tags: javascript, yammer

I am using the [Yammer Embed](https://developer.yammer.com/connect/) JavaScript control in an external web application.

I want to use the open-graph feature so that comments made are linked back to the page they were created on. This is all very simple, but the question I have is that I want the posts to go to a specific group (instead of "My Colleagues"). When the user is creating the post, they have the option to change it to whatever group they want, but it defaults to "My Colleagues". I am fine with them having the option to post it to whatever groups they want, but I would like the option to default to a specific group. Is this possible? Unfortunately there isn't good documentation on all the options that can be used with `yam.connect.embedFeed`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just released this feature.  Documentation is to be updated very soon,  use "defaultGroupId" inside your config to get your group selected.

Comment: Is there are way to default to 'All Company' when using the Yammer Embedded Widget w/ Open Graph?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not an option today with OG object feeds. We are aware of the need for this. I hope this will be addressed in the not too distant future because it's a bugbear.