# Yammer Open-graph and Commenting

Tags: facebook-opengraph, yammer

I have this code, no API nor nothing, I simply would like to get a Group ID inside here for it to be the default option for where to share the comment and embed the comment stream on Yammer, is this even possible? Is there a way to block the possibility of selection from all your groups and leave it to just one?

```
  <script>
yam.connect.embedFeed({
 container: "#embedded-feed",
 feedType: "open-graph",
 config: {
   header: true,
   footer: false,
   promptText: "Remember to select a Group and/or person",
   showOpenGraphPreview: true,
 }
});
    </script>
```

The Code is working, but I just need to filter that option
Thank you

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785119/setting-default-target-group-with-yammer-embed-and-open-graph/21799770#21799770.

Answer (score 1):

We just released this feature.  Documentation is to be updated very soon,  use "defaultGroupId" inside your config to get your group selected.

Answer (score 1):

i have done a simple implementation like this.

```
 var generateYammerFeeds = function(title, description) {
    try {
        yam.connect.embedFeed({
            container: "#yammerDiscussion",
            network: "abc.com",
            feedType: "open-graph",
            objectProperties: {
                fetch: true,
                private: false,
                ignore_canonical_url: false,
                url: location.href,
                type: "page",
                title: title,
                image: '',
                description: description
            },
            config: {
                header: true,
                footer: true,
                showOpenGraphPreview: false,
                defaultToCanonical: true,
                hideNetworkName: true,
                promptText: "Ask a Question",
                defaultGroupId: 121212
            }
        });
        return true;
    } catch (e) {
        return null;
    }
};
```